# autorelease interior pointer/object?

Tags: objective-c

Suppose I have this code:

```
-(SomeOtherType*) getMyObject {
    SomeType someObject = [[SomeType alloc] init];
    // ... later on
    SomeOtherType toReturn = [[[someObject interiorObject] retain] autorelease];
    [someObject release];
    return toReturn;
}
```

The `toReturn` object, am I handling it correctly? I want to deliver it as an `autoreleased` object, but I do want to scrap `someObject`. Is this *the* pattern to transfer ownership? I've gone over it in my head and on paper, and it seems OK, but I'd rather be informed by someone more enlightened.

**Edit** This is a very contrived example, just to illustrate the problem at hand. `someObject` lives across many method calls, and in the end, I want to "dump its guts". This is NOT a Daily WTF example. Please don't ridicule me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have provided in your question is correct. Lets go over why. When thinking about retain/release you need to think about ownership. Objects are typically owned by another object or within some particular scope. In this case `getByObject`'s scope. The object you want to return is the `interiorObject` which is owned by `someObject`. But you need to release `someObject` before you return. The proper thing to do is take ownership of the `interiorObject` and return an autoreleased copy. And finally release or autorelease `someObject`.

If ownership was not acquired to the `interiorObject` before the release of `someObject` then the `interiorObject` could be deallocated and we would be returning a dangling pointer. The first time someone tries to send a message to it the program would likely crash.

Comment: Thank you! I'm finally starting to wrap my head around this. :)

Comment: I also recommend: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html. It has useful information on how to write the code correctly and how to debug issues you are likely to encounter.

Comment: Just to make sure that I truly understood this: If I was sure that interiorObject exists after deallocating someObject, i wouldn't have retain and autorelease it, right? I might be risky but i'd actually work?

Comment: @Larcus94 If the retain count is >0 the object will be alive. So if interiorObject had a retain count >=2  even after one of it's owners is dealloced it would still be alive. So yes you could write code like that. It's not risky. It's very very wrong and will fail. And it will fail in ways that are time consuming to debug. So in short. Don't do that. Take ownership of objects that you need to exist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure you need to do the `retain` / `autorelease` dance unless your expecting another thread to potentially deallocate your object?

```
- (SomeOtherType *)getMyObject
{
    SomeType someObject = [[SomeType alloc] init];
    // ... later on

    SomeOtherType toReturn = [someObject interiorObject];
    [someObject release];
    return toReturn;
}
```

The `retain` / `autorelease` dance will guarantee that the object hangs around to the end of the runloop even if another thread releases it's retains on it.

Comment: Isn't this guaranteed anyway as long as interiorObject returns an autoreleased object?

Comment: @Larcus94 Most likely `YES` but it depends on how `interiorObject` is defined for example it could potentially be `@property (nonatomic, assign) id interiorObject;`

Comment: `interiorObject` just returns a reference to an object owned by `someObject`. One can assume that the ref count of `toReturn` will be 1. Because of that, `toReturn` will become a dangling pointer once `[someObject release]` has been called (because I `release` the interior object in `dealloc` of `someObject`). Regardless of threading...